# Route not executing after middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So I'm creating an authentication route but failing after executing the middleware.

**verifyToken.js**

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
const token = req.get('auth-token')
if (!token) return res.status(401).send('Access Denied!')
try {
    const verified = jwt.verify(token, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET)
    req.user = verified
    console.log(req.user) // successfully logging
    next()
} catch (err) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.status(403).send('Invalid Token')
}
}
```

**user.controller.js**

```
exports.currentUser = verifyToken, async (req, res) => { // after verify token throwing an error 404
   console.log('HIT') // not logging
   // return res.send(req.user)
}
```

**user.route.js**

```
const { currentUser } = require('../controllers/users');
router
   .route('/currentuser')
   .post(currentUser)
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code and I couldn't log 'HIT' as well. I suggest the following, split the exports @ exports.currentUser into

```
var verifyToken = require('./verifyToken.js')

var response = async (req, res) => {
   console.log('HIT') // not logging
   // return res.send(req.user)
}

module.exports.currentUser = {verifyToken, response}
```

Then re-write route.js like this to get it to work.

```
const { currentUser } = require('./controller.js');
router.get('/currentUser', currentUser.verifyToken, currentUser.response)
```

To utilize next(), I had to use router.get('/get', middleware, callback). I changed the codes so that I could test it. You will need to edit the codes according to your context!

Comment: The way I structured my code was to make it more neat/clean i guess thats why I added a `controller.js` looks like I will have to removed it and just use only routes to handle request.

Comment: No! There's no need to remove the controller.js. You can keep verifyToken and async(req,res) callback in the same file as long as you name them and export them as an object! Just some minor tweaks as shown in my answer.